# Combinatory Explanation for $ \sum_{k=1}^{100} {{100} \choose {k}}2^k=3^{100}-1 $

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

How do I Explain this Combinatory? $$ \sum_{k=1}^{100} {{100} \choose {k}}2^k=3^{100}-1 $$

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya yes thank you !

Comment: If explictly looking for a combinatorial explanation... Consider the number of ternary strings (*strings made with digits 0,1,2*) with at least one non-$2$.  On the right, count directly.  On the left, first pick the locations and then the values of each non-$2$, ranging over all possible numbers of non-$2$'s.

Comment: @JMoravitz that's good!